# Where can I find demographic data on ABC network shows?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, metadata

Does anyone know where I can find data on **ABC network** shows (like **Blackish** on ABC Family)? I want to see how they're doing as a company and what their **demographics** numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a good amount of data from UCLA's [Hollywood Diversity Report](https://socialsciences.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/UCLA-Hollywood-Diversity-Report-2018-2-27-18.pdf). Linked is the one for 2018, but is seems they do one every year.

So far, I've only been able to find a PDF.